# Java script code is not working? Please help me

Tags: javascript, validation

I am trying to validate visa card number with a Luhn algorithm. But this java script code is not working?  Please help me to find the error of this code. Is it possible to execute this code? ANy kind of help appreciated. Thanks in advance...

```
function allnumeric()  
            {   
            var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;  
            if(inputtxt.value.match(numbers))  
                {  
                    if(function visa(inputtxt))

                    {

                        if(function luhn(inputtxt))

                        {
                        return true;
                        }
                        else  
                        {   
                        return false;  
                        }

                    }


            else  
            {  
            alert('Please enter your valid 10 digit mobile number only');  
            inputtxt.focus();  
            return false;  
            } 

function visa(inputtxt)  
{  
  var cardno = /^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?)$/;  
  if(inputtxt.value.match(cardno))  
        {  
      return true;  
        }  
      else  
        {  
        alert("Not a valid Visa credit card number!");  
        return false;  
        }  
}  

function luhn(inputtxt)
{
            /* Luhn check */
            var cc_sum = 0;
            var parsedCC;
            var cclen = inputtxt.length;
            for (i=cclen-1; i>=0; i--) {
                    var charati = inputtxt[i] + '';
                    parsedCC = parseInt(charati);
                    var oddeven = cclen-1 - i;
                    cc_sum += (oddeven%2 == 0) ? parsedCC :
                                    (parsedCC > 4) ? parsedCC * 2 % 10 + 1 :
                                            parsedCC * 2;
            }
            var checkvalid = ((cc_sum % 10) == 0) ? true : false;
            return checkvalid;
}
```

Comment: On a serious note here: questions on Stack Overflow are expected to show some effort on the asker side and explaining what was done in the process of trying. Also it's expected from the asker to have some basic knowledge in the area he's asking about.

Answer (score 1):

remove `function` from your code when calling visa and luhn:

**EDIT: I have removed unnecessary code:**

```
function allnumeric()  
{   
    var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;  
    if(inputtxt.value.match(numbers))  
    {  
        if(visa(inputtxt))
        {
            return luhn(inputtxt);
        }
        else 
        {
            alert('Please enter your valid 10 digit mobile number only');  
            inputtxt.focus();  
            return false;  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: don't repost a wall of text where you've changed only a few characters. Pull out a small relevant snippet and show where the change is.

Comment: Thats all! Thanks for your help dear... Changing it now :)

Comment: I have shortened a bit your allnumeric function and removed the unnecessary code as @MarcB suggested